# vb code error to get difference between a textbox value from the current date

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to get the difference between a textbox value(selected date from ajax calender) and the current date. I an using the following code.

```
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click
        Dim res As Integer
        Dim quantity As String
        Dim status = "fresh" 'calculate dates of harvest and today to find it is fresh or not
        Dim fid As Integer
        Dim today As Date = Date.Today
        Dim harvest As String
        harvest = txtharvest.Text
        Dim myDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(harvest, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)
        Dim num As Integer


        'fid = Convert.ToInt32(Session("user"))
        'quantity = txtquantity.Text + ":" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text
        ' res=db.exenon("insert into Productforselling(categoryid,productname,location,harvestingdate,bestbefore,quantity,pricefor1kg,photo,farmerid,status) values("& Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value) &",'"+txtname.Text+"','"+txtloc.Text+"','"+txtharvest.Text+"','"+txtbest.Text+"','"+quantity+"','"+txtprice.Text+"','"+FileUpload1.FileName+"'," & fid & ",
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try DateDiff function to find the difference between to dates.

You can try following to find the difference

```
DateDiff("d",myDate,today)
```

More about datediff at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx

Hope this help!